# Calling PowerShell functions in another scripts

Tags: script, powershell

I have a script with a number of functions (not just functions but also other code).  I would like to create another script that uses one of the functions in the main script.  Here is a sample of what I am trying to do.  In my **test.ps1** script:

```
function Test1 {Write-Host “This is test1”}
function Test2 {Write-Host “This is test2”}

Test1
Test2
```

And inside of the **testtest.ps1** script:

```
. ".\test.ps1"
Test1
```

When I run **test.ps1**, the output is:

```
This is test1
This is test2
```

When I run **testtest.ps1**, the output is:

```
This is test1
This is test2
This is test1
```

All I want to do is to call the Test1 function in my **test.ps1** script from my **testtest.ps1** script.  One of my conditions is that we not change the **test.ps1** script (due to permission issues, read versus write folder access) and I don't want to duplicate script code (which is why I'm trying to reuse code).

I can't find the solution that I need, everyone talks about dot-sourcing with PowerShell.  So is dot-sourcing the proper way to do this or is there some other way to use (only) a function from another PowerShell script without running the remaining code in that script?

Thanks

Comment: Just trying to clarify: So you're trying to include ("dot-source") the Test.ps1 file in testtest.ps1 so you can use the functions from it, but when you do it's running the body of the included script (test.ps1)?

Comment: See this SO question: [In powershell, how do I define a function in a file and call it from the powershell commandline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016436/in-powershell-how-do-i-define-a-function-in-a-file-and-call-it-from-the-powersh).  Specifically for alternatives see [this answer regarding using modules instead of dot-source includes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6040725/225906).

Comment: Or make a file that has just the functions in it and not all the extra code. Then dot source that.

Comment: @techie007 - That is correct, exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: I can't change what is already there...So changing or altering the existing PS script with the function (i.e., making a module for just functions) won't work.  Then the code is in more than one location.  I'm hoping that there is a way to just call a function inside another PS script without running the rest of that script.

Comment: Then the last, least desirable, most annoying option is to write your own code to parse out just the functions from the other file. If keeping the code in just one place is the goal (and that is a great goal), then the solution is to make a third file that is just the functions then dot source that in both of the other scripts. Then the function code still only lives one place.

Comment: Thanks @EBGreen unfortunately that leaves me stuck (since I can't modify the original source).  But I appreciate the feedback!!

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a way to do this so I'll post it in case it helps anyone else.  Granted I did have to edit the original PS script but the changes made are negligible and they don't impact the primary processing of the script at all.

Contents of the **test.ps1** script:

```
Param ([int]$Local)

function Test1 {Write-Host “This is test1”}
function Test2 {Write-Host “This is test2”}

If ($Local -eq 1) {Exit}

Test1
Test2
```

Contents of the **testtest.ps1** script:

```
. ".\test.ps1" -Local 1
Test1
```

When I run **test.ps1**, I get:

```
This is test1
This is test2
```

But now (with the changes made), when I run **testtest.ps1**, I get:

```
This is test1
```

This way, the script has loaded the functions from test.ps1 into memory (so that they can be used) but it doesn't process any part of the remainder of the script (because we Exit).  Now I can use the functions located in this script if I want without affecting the processing of the original source script.

Thanks to all for the feedback!!